# Virtualbox fails when I'm connected to an OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, vpn, openvpn

Some days ago, VirtualBox started to fail when I'm connected to a VPN. If my computer isn't connected to the VPN, everything works fine. I can start VMs, stop them, and so on. But if **my computer is connected to the VPN**, I get these messages:

```
$ VBoxManage controlvm myvm pause
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage: error: Code NS_ERROR_ABORT (0x80004004) - Operation aborted (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

This is my configuration:

- Mac OS X El Capitan
- VirtualBox 5.0.26 r108824
- Tunnelblick 3.6.7c (build 4606) as VPN client
- OpenVPN server 2.1.3

Just in case, the OpenVPN server is not installed on my computer. It's on a server in my new office.

What would be the problem?

**EDIT:** I just connected to a different VPN and VirtualBox worked with no problem. Now I'm sure the problem is caused for some configuration in the OpenVPN server.

Comment: A wild guess would be that `VBoxManage` uses some kind of IP socket to some other process which actually manages the  VMs.  When connected to the VPN, your network configuration is changed in a way that confuses `VBoxManage` about how to connected to the daemon.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @VadimShender  Yes! Some months ago. I just added as an answer.

Comment: @JonDoe297, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my OpenVPNAS server, I deleted the value on "Configuration > VPN Settings > Default Domain Suffix (optional)" and VirtualBox worked again.:

[image: OpenVPNAS Screenshot]